Using `numba` to speed up vectorization on very large `numpy` arrays
I originally had some code that operates on very large arrays using for loops. I wanted to see if I can speed it up with numpy and numba and tried 4 incremental steps to get it faster.
Setup:
from timeit import timeit

import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

TIMESTAMPS = 3
REGIONS = 150
HEIGHT = 240
WIDTH = 320

TRIALS = 100

np.random.seed(0)

FRAME_MASKS = np.ascontiguousarray(
    np.random.randint(0, 2, (TIMESTAMPS, HEIGHT, WIDTH), dtype=bool)
)
REGION_MASKS = np.ascontiguousarray(
    np.random.randint(0, 2, (REGIONS, HEIGHT, WIDTH), dtype=bool)
)
REGION_AREAS = np.sum(REGION_MASKS, axis=(-1, -2))

# OLFR = "Overlap of Frames with Regions"

# Run once to compile the code (although this is not trivial either...)
olfr_native_for_loops(*test_params)
olfr_fully_vectorized(*test_params)
olfr_with_numba(*test_params)
olfr_all_flags_numba(*test_params)

...

# Timing
test_params = (FRAME_MASKS, REGION_MASKS, REGION_AREAS)
for prefix, func in [
    ["for_loops", lambda: olfr_native_for_loops(*test_params)],
    ["fully_vectorized", lambda: olfr_fully_vectorized(*test_params)],
    ["with_numba", lambda: olfr_with_numba(*test_params)],
    ["all_flags_numba", lambda: olfr_all_flags_numba(*test_params)],
]:
    speed = timeit(func, number=TRIALS)
    print(f"Done. {prefix} speed={speed:.4f}")


Native for loops

def olfr_native_for_loops(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    ratios = np.zeros((TIMESTAMPS, REGIONS))

    for t in range(TIMESTAMPS):
        for r in range(REGIONS):
            raw_intersection = frame_masks[t] & region_masks[r]
            intersection_area = np.sum(raw_intersection, axis=(-1, -2))
            ratios[t, r] = intersection_area / region_areas[r]

    return ratios

Done. for_loops speed=2.0005

It has some vectorization as I learned in StackOverflow - 38760898 - np-newaxis-with-numba-nopython, but the for loops are easy to vectorize so I tried that next.

Fully vectorized

def olfr_fully_vectorized(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    raw_intersection = frame_masks[:, np.newaxis, ...] & region_masks[np.newaxis]
    intersection_area = np.sum(raw_intersection, axis=(-1, -2))
    ratios = intersection_area / region_areas
    return ratios

Done. fully_vectorized speed=2.4903

This is great, because it is clean, but it got slower. As mentioned in StackOverflow - 38760898, this isn't too surprising because the array is huge so it is probably getting evicted from the memory cache more easily.
So I want a solution that allows me to write vectorized code, but get the performance benefits of smaller array sizes that don't get evicted from the cache.
In my production example, I saw CPU usage was half what the "native python" solution had, so I assumed BLAS was not able to schedule enough threads to parallelize these operations (a separate issue) so I turned to numba.

Regular numba

@nb.njit
def olfr_with_numba(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    raw_intersection = frame_masks.reshape(TIMESTAMPS, 1, -1) & region_masks.reshape(
        1, REGIONS, -1
    )
    intersection_area = np.sum(raw_intersection, axis=-1)
    result = intersection_area / region_areas
    return result

Done. with_numba speed=14.7773

Okay, now it got even slower. Fine, I read more docs and learned that numba is not great with big arrays (StackOverflow - 57819913#7460739), and that I should enable the flags of numba.

numba with flags

@nb.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True, nogil=True, cache=True)
def olfr_all_flags_numba(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    raw_intersection = frame_masks.reshape(TIMESTAMPS, 1, -1) & region_masks.reshape(
        1, REGIONS, -1
    )
    intersection_area = np.sum(raw_intersection, axis=-1)
    result = intersection_area / region_areas
    return result

Done. all_flags_numba speed=7.6477

That helped, but we're still worse than where we started.
In my production code I am able to successfully make it faster by using from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool and sending out threads for all my slow "huge vectorization" operations, but why can't BLAS/numba do that for me automatically?
Thank you in advance!
PS: My AWS c5.4xlarge CPU stats are below (I've seen a bigger L3 cache make fully_vectorized go faster, but that's the point of this question: what library can automatically split the array so it can stay in the L1/L2 cache as much as possible)
CPU(s):              16
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-15
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             3400.948
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            1024K
L3 cache:            25344K


Quick check, the ratios in olfr_native_for_loops are created as int32, but should this be float32 ?

One more thing, are the parameters in the code example the size of the array you are actually working with, or did you choose small numbers for testing purposes? I mean, are you trying to make it faster because you will be using it repeatedly, or are you trying to make it faster so you can use it with larger arrays?

@ken thanks for your prompt! Yes it should have been float32 so I just removed dtype and let it be my machine word size. Yes I was using an axis=0 heavy size dimension and good point because I heard numpy prefers front loaded arrays. I changed it to be more realistic! Same timings all-around!

Numba isn't likely to make a vectorized numpy approach faster, but it may make the looping solution faster.

what is the reason for np.sum(raw_intersection, axis=(-1, -2)) to use axis at all if you are including all axes? If you can simplify to np.sum(raw_intersection), you can simply add @nb.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True, nogil=True, cache=True) to olfr_native_for_loops for a good speedup. On my machine: for_loops speed=1.9221, numba_loop speed=0.9381.

@Aaron Interestingly, Numba generates a completely different SIMD assembly code when axis is not used removing the port 5 bottleneck on Intel CPUs (see my answer for more information about it). With a special ware on where prange is applied, this solution is quite good actually (I added it in the answer).

@Aaron you're correct! I confirmed what you discovered. axis=(-1,2) is not needed because the for loops already break it down to the optimal size. That's a great lesson :) However, my original goal was to use more vectorization. Otherwise now I need special knowledge to "smartly" break down the loop so that I don't need axis in my np.sum.... Shouldn't there be a library (i.e. BLAS) that can break down the operation into this optimal "small" array? (i.e. "cache tiling size" as in https://siboehm.com/articles/22/Fast-MMM-on-CPU) Anyways this is a good answer, please submit it!

@NathanielRuiz looks like Jérôme already has the answer covered. I just wanted to point out that Numba filps the paradigm of python speed on its head. Loops can be fast, but it can't do anything to make numpy functions any faster.

TL;DR: Numba generates a significantly-less efficient assembly code than Numpy, especially on Intel CPUs like your (due to a port 5 saturation). Numba also poorly parallelize the code since it seems only to consider the first axis for the parallelization while it could operate on both first and the second one (collapse).

Performance results and setup
First thing first, I am able to reproduce the Numba performance issue on my Debian Linux with a i5-9600KF CPU, a ~40 GiB/s RAM, with CPython 3.11.6, Numpy 1.24.2 and Numba 0.57.1. However, I am not able to reproduce the slower Numpy execution for the vectorized code. Here are the performance results:
# Time per run (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
olfr_native_for_loops:       15.5 ms ± 63.2 µs
olfr_fully_vectorized:       15.3 ms ± 85.6 µs
olfr_with_numba:             91.3 ms ± 54.6 µs
olfr_all_flags_numba:        61.7 ms ± 111 µs


Performance of the Numpy codes

It has some vectorization as I learned in StackOverflow - 38760898 - np-newaxis-with-numba-nopython, but the for loops are easy to vectorize so I tried that next.


This is great, because it is clean, but it got slower. As mentioned in StackOverflow - 38760898, this isn't too surprising because the array is huge so it is probably getting evicted from the memory cache more easily.

This is indeed totally right. I mentioned a similar issue in your previous post.
However, the timings are about the same on my machine. This is because the additional memory pressure is not big enough to make the whole code slow on my machine. We can see that by analyzing the RAM throughput on both codes:
olfr_native_for_loops:  1.0 GiB/s (99% loads,  1% stores)
olfr_fully_vectorized:  6.4 GiB/s (69% loads, 31% stores)

We can see that the vectorized implementation significantly put more pressure on the RAM (6.4 times more). This is due to large temporary arrays as expected (they need to be stored and read back). This vectorized code can typically be slower on machines with a small RAM bandwidth (i.e. not on my machine). It also requires more memory so it can be a problem on machines with a very small amount of memory. The first version computing chunks should be clearly preferred over the later (at least regarding performance).

So I want a solution that allows me to write vectorized code, but get the performance benefits of smaller array sizes that don't get evicted from the cache.

This is unfortunately not possible with Numpy to automatically merge operations in order to execute them in an efficient interleaved way. Such an operation is sometimes called kernel merging. Modules like CuPy (a Numpy-like module for Nvidia GPUs) can do such a thing in simple cases. I think Dask can do it too (AFAIK Numpy is used as a backend for Dask and Dask arrays are a grid of Numpy arrays). AFAIK, NumExpr can do that in simple cases too. For complex cases, it is a rather difficult research problem (I actually worked on this during my PhD thesis).

Performance of the Numba code

Fine, I read more docs and learned that numba is not great with big arrays (StackOverflow - 57819913#7460739)

This tends to be often right. Indeed, Numpy is manually optimized to use SIMD instructions when the compiler fail to do that automatically. Numba don't do that (certainly for sake of maintainability). Thus, Numpy tends to be faster when operating on large arrays. Numpy codes are slow on code operating on many small arrays or iterating on scalar because of the (quite big) Numpy function call overhead and interpreted CPython loops. This is why vectorization (i.e. calling C functions from Python) is generally a very good idea performance-wise. However, this simply does not apply to Numba. Numba loops are fast (as fast as C ones and so the one of the Numpy implementation). Since registers are faster than memory, it is actually often better to use loops in Numba. However, sometimes it is faster to operate on chunks (like the first code) because compilers can sometimes fail to generate SIMD instructions when the code do not operate on small arrays. The best is to check the generated code, but it unfortunately is not simple for non expert to extract the assembly code of the executed sections and understand it correctly.

I should enable the flags of numba.

The added flags does not really solve the problem.

parallel=True just uses more core to do the operation, but it turns out that Numba does not succeed to use all the available core so the performance improvement is not great. On my machine, overall, it only barely uses 3 of the 6 available cores. It seems because TIMESTAMPS is set to 3 and there is not enough available parallelism on the first axis (although Numba could consider the second one...);
fastmath=True tells Numba that it can more aggressively optimize floating-point operations (e.g. assume that there is no NaN values and that FP operations are associative while they are actually not). Note it can sometimes be dangerous and break codes if the assumptions are not true. Here it is useless since the code operate on integers.
nogil=True is AFAIK useless here since the GIL should be disabled anyway (it is mandatory for parallel Numba codes);
cache=True tells Numba to put the generate code in a cache so to avoid recompiling the function later, but the compilation time is not the issue.


In my production code I am able to successfully make it faster by using from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool and sending out threads for all my slow "huge vectorization" operations, but why can't BLAS/numba do that for me automatically?

This is actually the purpose of parallel=True flag but the automatic parallelization of code is often not very efficient. In fact, it is not just Numba but this approach tend not to be efficient, especially on machine with many cores. It is often better to manually parallelize a loop with prange and avoid temporary arrays (while still using parallel=True or otherwise prange is simply useless).
Note that no BLAS is used here (BLAS are generally used for matrix-matrix/matrix-vector/vector-vector multiplications, but not for such operation, especially not on integers).

That helped, but we're still worse than where we started.

Indeed.
We can profile the code using objmode to find out that the two first lines are slow and the np.sum is slowest part:
raw_intersection computation:   41 ms
intersection_area computation:  50 ms
Final result computation:       <1 ms

My hypothesis is that the Numba code of the np.sum is much slower either because Numba generates a significantly less-efficient SIMD code in this case on most Intel CPUs as opposed to Numpy. Unfortunately, this is difficult to prove that since the generated assembly code is really huge (5000 lines), it is also complex with many generated variants, and it is not possible yet to use low-level profiler on the binaries generated by Numba (so I cannot know which variant is actually executed). On top of that, I often found that logical binary AND operations are slow because Numba does not generate a SIMD code but a scalar one (or sometimes a really inefficient SIMD code).
That being said, here is the kind of loop generated by Numba for the np.sum (AT&T assembly syntax -- one of the dozens of generated variants):
.LBB4_111:
    vmovdqu (%rcx), %ymm3
    vmovdqu 32(%rcx), %ymm4
    vmovdqu 64(%rcx), %ymm5
    vmovdqu 96(%rcx), %ymm6
    vperm2i128  $32, %ymm5, %ymm3, %ymm7
    vperm2i128  $32, %ymm6, %ymm4, %ymm8
    vperm2i128  $49, %ymm5, %ymm3, %ymm3
    vperm2i128  $49, %ymm6, %ymm4, %ymm4
    vpunpcklqdq %ymm8, %ymm7, %ymm5
    vpunpcklqdq %ymm4, %ymm3, %ymm6
    vpunpckhqdq %ymm8, %ymm7, %ymm7
    vpunpckhqdq %ymm4, %ymm3, %ymm3
    vpbroadcastb    (%rdx), %xmm4
    vpcmpeqb    %xmm2, %xmm4, %xmm4
    vpxor   %xmm1, %xmm4, %xmm4
    vpmovzxdq   %xmm4, %ymm4
    vpand   %ymm0, %ymm4, %ymm4
    vpaddq  %ymm4, %ymm5, %ymm5
    vpaddq  %ymm4, %ymm7, %ymm7
    vpaddq  %ymm4, %ymm6, %ymm6
    vpaddq  %ymm4, %ymm3, %ymm3
    vinserti128 $1, %xmm6, %ymm5, %ymm4
    vinserti128 $1, %xmm3, %ymm7, %ymm8
    vperm2i128  $49, %ymm6, %ymm5, %ymm5
    vperm2i128  $49, %ymm3, %ymm7, %ymm3
    vpunpcklqdq %ymm8, %ymm4, %ymm6
    vpunpcklqdq %ymm3, %ymm5, %ymm7
    vpunpckhqdq %ymm8, %ymm4, %ymm4
    vpunpckhqdq %ymm3, %ymm5, %ymm3
    vmovdqu %ymm7, 64(%rcx)
    vmovdqu %ymm3, 96(%rcx)
    vmovdqu %ymm6, (%rcx)
    vmovdqu %ymm4, 32(%rcx)
    subq    $-128, %rcx
    addq    $4, %rax
    jne .LBB4_111

While this code uses SIMD units (instructions starting with v here), it is especially slow for one reason on my machine: it converts 8-bit boolean items to 64-bit ones on-the-fly using the instructions vperm2i128, vpunpcklqdq and vpunpckhqdq and this specific set of instruction is inefficient on many Intel CPUs. More specifically, this issue impacts at least Haswell/Broadwell CPU and Skylake/KabyLake/CoffeeLake/CometLake CPU, but significantly-less IceLake CPUs and newer CPUs. Your CPU is a Skylake-based CPU like mine (CoffeeLake) so it is strongly impacted by this performance issue. To understand more precisely why, one should understand how Skylake-based CPUs execute instructions. All variants suffer from this same problem.
Each Skylake CPU core are can decode and execute multiple instructions in parallel in a out-of-order way. More specifically, it can execute multiple instructions like vpaddq at the same time thanks to a superscalar execution. Each of this instruction operate on many items at the same time thanks to SIMD units. Once decoded, instructions are scheduled on execution ports. Skylake-based cores have 8 execution ports. Most execution ports are specialized so they can only execute a specific set of instructions. For example, the port 4 can only store data in memory. The port 5 is the only one that can execute instructions vperm2i128, vpunpcklqdq and vpunpckhqdq (which are massively used in the Numba generated code of np.sum). Meanwhile, the vpaddq instructions can be executed on the ports 0, 1 and 5. Note that things are actually much more complex than that, but I simplified things a big for sake of clarity.
The thing is most instructions of the loop can only be executed on the port 5 which is completely saturated. Indeed, on the above variant, it is 18 instructions over 36. As a result, each iteration of the loop take at least 18 cycles. In fact, it is the main bottleneck so each iteration should actually take this time (or a bit more since the instruction scheduler is not perfect). Note that some other variants are even worsts than this one.
Numpy performs a completely different approach : it firsts convert the boolean array to 64-bit integers and then perform the sum on it pretty efficiently. Here is the code doing the sum:
add          $0x1,%rax
shl          $0x5,%rdi
vmovdqu      (%rsi,%rdi,1),%xmm6
vinserti128  $0x1,0x10(%rsi,%rdi,1),%ymm6,%ymm0
vpaddq       %ymm0,%ymm1,%ymm1
cmp          %rax,%r8
jne          438


The downside of this approach is that it tends to use significantly more memory and saturate the memory bandwidth. Thus, the Numpy code is more likely to be memory-bound. That being said, the Numpy conversion code is certainly also limited a bit by the port 5, although the code generated by GCC is better than the one of Numba (LLVM). On my machine, the conversion is particularly expensive : it takes >50% of the execution time!

Faster Numpy implementation
The thing is we do not need 64-bit integer for the sum. Indeed, we add boolean so 32-bit integers are far enough as long as we add less than <2e9 boolean items (so not to cause an overflow). Using 32-bit integers instead of 64-bit ones not only reduce the pressure on the port 5 but also save some memory (both the amount of memory required and bandwidth), not to mention this make the computation more cache friendly due to a smaller amount of memory used! 16-bit should be even better but note that they can only be used to sum 65535 boolean items (assuming the integer is unsigned -- i.e. np.uint16) while the two last axis have 240*320=76800 items.
Based on this, we can conclude that we should use 32-bit integers in the Numpy code for better performance. This can be easily done with the dtype parameter of np.sum. Here is the corrected Numpy code:
def olfr_faster_numpy_int32(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    ratios = np.zeros((TIMESTAMPS, REGIONS))

    for t in range(TIMESTAMPS):
        for r in range(REGIONS):
            raw_intersection = frame_masks[t] & region_masks[r]
            intersection_area = np.sum(raw_intersection, axis=(-1, -2), dtype=np.int32)
            ratios[t, r] = intersection_area / region_areas[r]

    return ratios

While it should be even faster with 16-bit integers (with 2 reduction steps so to avoid overflow), it is in practice not faster (due to Numpy overheads).
Another approach is simply to use the very optimized np.count_nonzero function instead of np.sum since the input are boolean numbers. It solves the bottlenecks related to the use of np.sum (no need to convert anything and Numpy already does the above optimization internally). However, Numba does not optimize np.count_nonzero yet (and I do not expect it to be as efficient as Numpy since Numpy developers manually use SIMD intrinsics in their code to aggressively optimize this function while Numba tends not to do that for sake of portability and maintainability).
Here is the modified code:
def olfr_faster_numpy_nnz(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    ratios = np.zeros((TIMESTAMPS, REGIONS))

    for t in range(TIMESTAMPS):
        for r in range(REGIONS):
            raw_intersection = frame_masks[t] & region_masks[r]
            intersection_area = np.count_nonzero(raw_intersection)
            ratios[t, r] = intersection_area / region_areas[r]

    return ratios


Faster Numba implementation
The same thing applies to Numba. However, we can write a more efficient code than the above Numpy one since we are not limited by the overhead of the Numpy internals anymore and we can avoid creating expensive temporary arrays too. All of this using plain basic loops (Numba like it liek native C code). On top of that, we can also use multiple threads easily in Numba but we need to collapse loops to get enough available parallelism.
Here is an optimized Numba implementation:
@nb.njit(parallel=True, cache=True)
def olfr_faster_numba(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    # Prevent Numba to read the global variables which are assume constant while they may not in practice
    TIMESTAMPS = frame_masks.shape[0]
    REGIONS = region_masks.shape[0]

    ratios = np.zeros((TIMESTAMPS, REGIONS))
    h, w = frame_masks.shape[-2:]
    assert region_masks.shape[-2] == h and region_masks.shape[-1] == w
    assert frame_masks.dtype.type is np.bool_
    assert region_masks.dtype.type is np.bool_

    # Collapse the r and t loops so to get more parallelism
    for tr in nb.prange(TIMESTAMPS * REGIONS):
        t = tr // REGIONS
        r = tr % REGIONS

        # Significantly speed up the next loop by avoiding inefficient boolean logical AND
        # since Numba do not like it at all, partially because of lazy evaluation 
        # (replace them with a binary AND like AFAIK Numpy does intenally)
        frame_masks_block = frame_masks[t].view(np.int8)
        region_masks_block = region_masks[r].view(np.int8)

        intersection_area = 0
        for y in range(h):
            # Use a 16-bit integer for the accumulator since 
            # it is better for SIMD units (faster)
            s = np.int16(0)
            for x in range(w):
                s += frame_masks_block[y,x] & region_masks_block[y,x]
            intersection_area += s

        ratios[t, r] = intersection_area / region_areas[r]

    return ratios

If you find this a bit too complicated, here is a trade-off solution which is simpler but a bit less efficient inspired by the comment of @Aaron:
@nb.njit(parallel=True, cache=True)
def olfr_faster_numba_simple(
    frame_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # T x H x W
    region_masks: npt.ArrayLike,  # R x H x W
    region_areas: npt.ArrayLike,  # R
):
    # Prevent Numba to read the global variables which are assume constant while they may not in practice
    TIMESTAMPS = frame_masks.shape[0]
    REGIONS = region_masks.shape[0]

    ratios = np.zeros((TIMESTAMPS, REGIONS))

    for r in nb.prange(REGIONS):
        for t in range(TIMESTAMPS):
            raw_intersection = frame_masks[t] & region_masks[r]
            intersection_area = np.sum(raw_intersection)
            ratios[t, r] = intersection_area / region_areas[r]

    return ratios

It is (almost magically) relatively fast because Numba surprisingly generates a completely different assembly code when np.sum does not have an axis argument! The generated code does not contain the 3 type of instructions saturating the port 5 like in the initial implementation so the main bottleneck just vanishes resulting in a significantly faster execution! It is still not as efficient as the above code since the sum is performed using 64-bit integers (and Numba does not support the dtype parameter yet).
Actually, there is an even faster implementation than the one proposed, but is a bit complex to implement, especially in Numba. One can convert boolean arrays to bit-fields (using np.packbits), then use binary AND so to compute the ANDs 8 times faster and finally use a popcnt x86-64 instruction so to count the number of 1 so to then put that in a 8-bit integer accumulator. This solution should be 8~10 times faster! Unfortunately popcnt is AFAIK not available in Numba so one may need to use a native language like C/C++ to do that. Interestingly, the next major version of Numpy (2.1) should introduce the new function bitwise_count which does exactly the operation needed (i.e. popcnt). It will then certainly take some times for the function to be integrated to Numba though.
Note that Numba compiles functions lazily at runtime so the first call may be slow. You can specify the signature to compile the function eagerly. However, this means you exactly know the type of the array (i.e. number of dimensions and item types as well as whether arrays are contiguous).

Discussion
I do not expect any magical tool to write the optimized Numba code. Besides, merging vectorized Numpy operations was actually a bad idea performance-wise with 64-bit integers on Intel CPU. I do not expect any tool to write the above Numba code or to generate a similar resulting assembly code. In fact, I expect such a magical tool not to solve such performance issue and to hide it further by merging kernels making profiling even harder. In general, low-level details matter a lot for performance, but high-level tools very often miss that (and it is too complex to consider both the many things that can happen on all available architectures and the possible specialized code we can write for the specific operation you want to perform).

Final performance results
# Time per run (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
olfr_native_for_loops:         15.5 ms ±  63.2 µs
olfr_fully_vectorized:         15.3 ms ±  85.6 µs
olfr_with_numba:               91.3 ms ±  54.6 µs
olfr_all_flags_numba:          61.7 ms ± 111.0 µs

# Time per run (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
olfr_faster_numpy_int32:       9.02 ms ± 11.3 µs
olfr_faster_numpy_nnz:         4.17 ms ±  3.3 µs
olfr_faster_numba_simple:      0.86 ms ± 26.2 µs
olfr_faster_numba:             0.66 ms ± 20.5 µs           <----------

Optimal time (memory-bound):   0.28 ms

The final optimized Numba implementation clearly outperform all other implementations by a large margin. It is 92 times faster than the initial parallel Numba implementation and 23 times faster than the fastest initial Numpy version. It is mostly because it uses multiple thread but the sequential version takes about 3.8 ms on my machine which is still faster than all other implementations, though the olfr_faster_numpy_nnz is pretty good (since it is sequential). The parallel Numba implementation scale very well.

Thank you again @Jérôme Richard, I'm so grateful! :) olfr_faster_numpy_nnz did got my code to run 30% faster! :) Probably due to slight differences in my code. The numba techniques didn't work most likely due to the same differences, but I learned so much and am excited to take this forward! Thanks again all!

Beautiful answer and analysis!

You are using global variables for array shapes in your code samples, which means they are hardcoded after compilation.  Without a change, the code samples  would crash or produce wrong results if the array shapes change after compilation. Maybe @NathanielRuiz run into this problem?

@mas9111 good point! My testing setup had global variables, but production would certainly be dynamic, so more of a reason why numba doesn't work for me I guess :') Thanks for your comment!

@NathanielRuiz No you can just use region_masks.shape[0] instead of REGIONS. Or you pass REGIONS to the function explicitely (which makes no sense, it is a property of an array anyway). The whole point is, that you know what's happening if you use global variables in Numba functions. They get hardcoded at compile-time, but I don't see any point why using them at all here.

Thanks for the kind comments :) . The performance on a Xeon Platinum 8124M CPU should be different certainly because of 1. wider SIMD units (AVX-512), 2. a bigger L3 cache, 3. a higher latency L3 cache (due to its bigger size and higher scalability), 4. lower frequency (like most Xeon CPUs), 5. a possibly higher memory bandwidth (IDK if you can use all the available RAM-channels / IMC-controllers due to a restricted number of allocated vCPUs). I it certainly a good idea to check what is the bottleneck (CPU or RAM) on your CPU regarding Numba.

Good point about the constants! I just kept the logic of the initial code but it matters for both performance (though the impact should be small), and flexibility. I will check the performance before editing that.

I just found out that the provided Numba version (olfr_faster_numba) was actually suspiciously slower on my machine while I could reproduce all other timings accurately. This was because the provided version was not the most optimized version and also not the one benchmarked ^^" (the one that was is the new version and I just forgot to update the code in the end). I fixed the answer. This might explain why "the numba techniques didn't work" though the previous Numba implementation was still faster than Numpy (~1.3 ms). Using locals instead of globals did not impact results as expected :) .

@NathanielRuiz Can you test the corrected Numba version. It tends to be more cache-friendly and scalable (which might have been the problem on your CPU).

@JérômeRichard thanks so much for your follow up! I gave it my all but I couldn't apply your techniques to solve my production use case :') I eventually got numba to go 4x faster than my vectorized solution, but the principles of olfr_faster_numpy_nnz was still 6x faster. Even so I couldn't go faster than the original "very minimal vectorization" solution. In my code, T is actually split into 3 different loops. Otherwise, line profiling says all my time goes to & (28%), count_nonzero (28%), and / (12%). I guess it'll be a mystery I don't solve for now, but I learned so much!
